# difference between request object and requesScope of java(Expression Launguage)

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, el, servlet-3.0

```
    Thank all of you,
    I am getting problem in getting value from requestScope in el statement,I tried one example. 
    index.jsp:
    <form name="frm" action="sample.jsp">
        Enter your name <input type="text" name="name">
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>

    sample.jsp:
    1 ${param.name}
    2 ${paramValues.name[0]} 
    3 ${pageContext.request.parameterMap.name[0]}
    4 <% out.println(request.getParameter("name"));%>
    5 ${requestScope.name}
```

While I am pressing submit button my output In first 4 statement I am getting output and 5 statement is null.As 3 and 4th statement are request i got desired result and 5th is also request but i am getting null ,can any one please explain difference.

Comment: @Bausc can u tell me why i am not getting output. if request and requestScope are equal as you given link.its challenge for u

Comment: When opening a question, scroll to bottom to see answers.